# jquery ui datepicker allows past dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I allow past dates as deep as possible in jquery ui datepicker?

```
$( ".date-picker" ).datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

these answers I found seem that you have to set a date in the past to start. But what if I want to allow the dates which were very very far in the past, such as in 1800s?

```
$('.date-picker').datePicker({startDate:'01/01/2000'});
$('.date-picker').datePicker({startDate: (new Date()).addYears(-1).asString()});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Set a date in the past? Set a min date in the past? Other?

Comment: just want to be able to select dates in the past - with no limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`changeYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear) parameter to `true` to display the year drop-down; this make the year selection easier. Also set the [`yearRange`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) parameter to specify the range of years; default is current year +/- 10 years:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1:c+10" // 1AD to 2013AD + 10
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/H7yrP/)

Answer (score 0):

Show the current example

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txt").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",changeYear:true
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<input type="text" id="txt" class=".date-picker"/>
```

you can select any date in past.
Open the year dropdownlist and select the older one then open it again and select the older.

Comment: This example will only let you see 10 years back (Which is the datepicker's default)